# WEB API Help page doesn't come up

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a combined MVC & WEB API Project using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage nuget.

The help page shows up in a colleague's computer in the url

> localhost:49432/help/

BUT, in my computer it just doesn't work, I am routed into a Directory Listing  page.

Why doesn't it work in my computer..? How can I debug the cause for it?

10x[image]

Comment: Are you referring to your friend's server by his IP or just `localhost` ?

Comment: `localhost` on your computer just refers to your computer. Unless you are hosting the same exact project in your own computer, you will have to use your friend's IP to access his server. You can get his IP by `ipconfig` in cmd prompt

Comment: I'm running the same code on my computer, not connected to my friend's computer in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have a folder called "help" in your project directory, which IIS is maybe routing to instead of your help area.